# How to find the index of the first instance of a list (in a list) containing the wanted value (in Python)?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that looks like the following

```
list_of_list = [(0,1,2), (0,1), (0,1,3,4), (0,1,2,3,4)]
```

I want to find the index for the first time I have a particular integer. For example, I want to find the first time 3 exists, and want it to return the index 2. I also want it to return `None` if it cannot find anything. I currently have the following code

```
def find_index_of_solution(list_of_list, value_I_am_searching_for):
  for idx, list_item in enumerate(list_of_list):
    if value_I_am_searching_for in list_item:
      return idx
  return None
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Personally, I would find your solution to be most readable and understandable. There are other ways to do the same thing, but even if they're slightly shorter, this seems simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours :

```
%%timeit
list_of_list = [(0,1,2), (0,1), (0,1,3,4), (0,1,2,3,4)]


def findIdx(list_of_list, value_I_am_searching_for):
    for idx, list_item in enumerate(list_of_list):
        if value_I_am_searching_for in list_item:
          return idx
    return None


findIdx(list_of_list, 3)


1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 µs per loop
```

Blue_note's :

```
%%timeit
list_of_list = [(0,1,2), (0,1), (0,1,3,4), (0,1,2,3,4)]
my_value = 3
try:
    return next(index for index, lst in enumerate(list_of_list) if my_value in lst)
except StopIteration:
    return None

1 loop, best of 3: 2 s per loop
```

Another one :

```
%%timeit
list_of_list = [(0,1,2), (0,1), (0,1,3,4), (0,1,2,3,4)]


def findIdx(lst, i):
    return [l.index(i) if i in l else 'None' for l in lst ]


findIdx(list_of_list, 3)

100000 loops, best of 3: 2 µs per loop
```

My opinion, stick with what you have for now..

Edit : 
I missed this ...

> For example, I want to find the first time 3 exists, and want it to
>   return the index 2.

nvm.

Comment: You can add a `break` statement right after you find the index of the first instance of `value_I_am_searching_for `.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    return next(index for index, lst in enumerate(list_of_list) if my_value in lst)
except StopIteration:
    return None
```

Inside the parentheses, is a generator expression. `next` returns the first element. `enumerate` is used to iterate over both index and value of an iterable. Finally, using an exception is preferred to checking in python, both as style and performance-wise